# Trying to configure NIS on a centos client and getting error Domain not bound

Tags: bind, nis, yp

I'm trying to set a host to use NIS.
I've instlled ypbind and yp-tools.
edited /etc/yp.conf:

```
domain mydomain.local server hostname
```

then edited: /etc/sysconfig/network and added:

```
NISDOMAIN="mydomain.local"
```

Then added the NIS server to the client's /etc/hosts file.
then i ran `#domainname mydomain.local.com and #ypdomainname mydomain.local`
and edited /etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:     files       nis
shadow:     files       nis
group:      files       nis
#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files nis dns
```

Then i've started the ypbind service and set chkconfig on it to on.
For some reason, while starting the ypbind service i get this error:

```
Binding NIS service: ......                                [FAILED]
```

If I ping mydomain.local i get a resolve and response.
When i su to my username i get the following error:

```
[root@itai-test ~]# su itaig
YPBINDPROC_DOMAIN: Domain not bound
[itaig@itai-test root]$
```

This is from /var/log/messages:

```
Jun 23 16:16:29 itai-test ypbind: NIS server for domain mydomain.local is not responding.
```

all though i know the NIS server serves IP to many other servers successfully.
Firewall is not running and iptables is disabled on the NIS client.
I've triple-checked all configuration files and i can't find what's wrong, maybe you'll be able to assist.

Comment: Check that the doamin name is correct in `/etc/defaultdomain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like network issues which has been solved caused this behavior.